# what is the best way to keep the Ubuntu system clean?

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, windows

In Windows, there are some apps which detect unnecessary files and remove them periodically.

I want to know what are the ways in which I can keep my Linux OS (mostly Ubuntu) clean? Like uninstalling apps which are not used over the last month, clearing the temporary files. Are there any apps for such to get it automatically done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with many ways.

- You can clean partial packages using below command

  ```
  sudo apt-get autoclean
  ```
- You can auto cleanup apt cache

  ```
  sudo apt-get clean
  ```
- You can cleaning up of any unused dependencies

  ```
  sudo apt-get autoremove
  ```
- You can use cleanup system tools like

  - Ubuntu Tweak
  - Sweeper
  - GCleaner

I hope it will help you to run your computer smoothly...